# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 10: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, typeerror, python-unicode

I got first these error:

```
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Then I added `iO` in front of `open`, but I got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 10: invalid start byte
```

```
class MySentences(object):

    def __init__(self, dirname, encoding='utf8'):
        self.dirname = dirname
        self.encoding = encoding 

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            sub_dir = os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)
            for fname in os.listdir(sub_dir):
                text_file = os.path.join(sub_dir, fname)
                for line in open(text_file, encoding=self.encoding):
                    yield nltk.word_tokenize(line, language='english')
```

Comment: Bytes 0xF5..0xFF (and also 0xC0, 0xC1) cannot appear in valid UTF-8.  Your data has 0xFB; that is invalid in UTF-8.  Your data is not, therefore, valid UTF-8 and the codec is correct to reject it.

Comment: Thank you. Data is the WikiExtractor´s output files from the English Wikipidia dump. What should I do to process it?

Comment: I've not looked at what the WikiExtractor's output is supposed to be.  You probably need a tool to look and see if that's the only problem, or just the first problem of many.  In the single-byte code set ISO 8859-1, 0xFB is U+00FB LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX.  I wonder if the data is in fact in 8859-1 rather than UTF-8?  I have such a program, written in C, but it is far too big to post here.  Contact me by email if you decide you need it — see my profile.  What is 'WikiExtractor' and how could I get the data you're trying to process?

Comment: You already have an encoding option already in your code. Just call `MySentences()` with `encoding="iso-8859-1"`. In Python 2.7, you should use `io.open()`, which supports decoding and universal newlines

Comment: Thank you @AlastairMcCormack io seems to work.